# getimagezise Error pasing filename

Tags: php

I am using getimagesize() to get teh size of my image. I have image in my sub-directory when i am passing file name with sub-directory i ma facing an error:

> There is no such file or directory

here is my Code:

```
<?PHP
        function resize($img,$max_w){
        $max_h=$max_w;
        list($img_w,$img_h) = getimagesize($img);
        $f = min($max_w/$img_w, $max_h/$img_h, 1);
        $w = round($f * $img_w);
        $h = round($f * $img_h); 
        return array($w,$h);
}

$filename="user_img/"."1256115556.jpg";
$resize=resize($filename,667);
$w=$resize[0];
$h=$resize[1];
?>
```

instead of this when i passing

```
$filename="1256115556.jpg";
```

file from my main directory the function is running perfectly. So please help me, How to pass file with sub-directory.

Comment: Add `echo realpath($filename);` to the end of your script and post the output. Check if the file really exists.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your directory name inside getimagesize(). Because the file name is a String.

```
list($img_w,$img_h) = getimagesize("user_img/".$img);
```

Its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a windows box then you might try a "\" and not a "/" in your path.

Comment: No i have tried this first but teh "\" becoming U and the whole picture name becoming user_imgU1256115556.jpg. Its not working as as well.